# Use NULL or nullptr for a C++ null pointer?

Tags: c++, null, clang

I am trying to make some Clang AST-dumps on dummy tests files. This is the command line I am using :

```
 clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only test.cpp
```

`int * a = NULL;` is recognized for my test.c, but not for my test.cpp.

I also tried `int * a = nullptr;` but that does not work aswell.

Should I change some options in my command line ?

Comment: For reference: [NULL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) ; [nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr)

Comment: `nullptr` is C++11 onwards. With which standard is your compiler compliant?

Comment: You'll either have to use `nullptr` and compile with c++11 compatibility, or use `NULL` and `#include` one of the C headers. Or you could always use `0`...

Comment: [`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) is defined in `<cstddef>`, is that your question?

Comment: Language support `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @Bathsheba : I am using OClint to build some static code analysis rules. OCLint recognizes C++11, but when I want to see the clang AST-dump outside of OClint (with a simple empty file and that `int * a = nullptr;` line, this Clang (which may not be the same as the Clang used in OClint) doesn't seem to understand C++11. So in previous C++ standards, what is the null keyword ?

Comment: Pre C++11 I *think* the best thing to do is to define it as `(void*)0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this command line:
**clang -std=c++11 -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only test.cpp**

now you can use `nullptr`

OR

```
#include <cstddef>
```

now you can use `NULL`

otherwise use `0`

Comment: Using 0 is in conflict with MISRA C++ rules that I must use. But the command line is correct ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

C++ prior to C++11 allowed either `NULL` (if you included the `cstddef` header file) or `0` itself.

I tend to prefer `NULL` because of my C background and I want to plainly see the difference between a null pointer and a zero value. However, some people prefer to just use `0`.

The introduction of `nullptr` in C++11 solved some problems, including which overloaded function to call when given a null pointer (one that takes an integer, or one that takes a pointer).

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL is appears that NULL is always "OK" when using cstddef?

Comment: Using 0 is in conflict with MISRA C++ rules that I must use. So I'd rather use cstddef ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use 0.

```
int *a = 0;
```

`nullptr` was introduced only in C++11. Pass the option -std=c++11 to your compiler. Does your version of clang support C++11? Regarding NULL see [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/NULL/)